# How to declare a variable which can contain only enum classes?

Tags: java

I tried this:

```
public static enum Types { A, B, C }
Class<Enum> e = Types.class;
```

But I get an "incompatible types" error:

```
found   : java.lang.Class<id.Types>
required: java.lang.Class<java.lang.Enum>
    Class<Enum> e = Types.class;
```

As far as I know all enums inherit from Enum. Why is my enum incompatible to Enum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just `Class<? extends Enum> e = Types.class;`?

**UPD:** I'll give you more explained answer, why your code does not work.

First of all, the type of expression `Types.class` is `Class<Types>`, and your variable `e` is `Class<Enum>`.

According to [JLS 5.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1) such types (i.e. `Class<Types>` and `Class<Enum>`) are provably distinct types ([JLS 4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5)), and their erasures are same (just `Class`), so in this case it is compile-time error when you try to cast from `Class<Types>` to `Class<Enum>`.

Comment: Thanks! But why is my enum no Enum?

Comment: @ceving your `Types` class is the class, which **extends** `Enum` class.

Comment: @ceving This also works. `Class<Enum> e = Enum.class;` `Enum` is the only class which is `Enum`, the others extend Enum.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes but normally I can assign child objects to parent variables. Why is it not possible for classes?

Comment: @ceving because generics are more pedantic as it is designed for containers (and containers need to be more specific about types).  You cannot assign an `Class<Types>` to a `Class<Enum>` because Types != Enum.  You have to use a `Class<? extends Enum>` as Types extends an Enum.

Comment: @ceving thanks for your approving my answer. Furthermore I gave you more detailed explanation in recent update

Comment: @Andremoniy but the erasure of Class<? extends Enum> is also Class, isn't it?

Comment: @ceving in this case their erasures don't matter: `|Class<Types>| <: |Class<? extends Enum>|` - so everything is ok.